# My laptop keep freezing

Tags: windows-10, laptop, freeze

I have a low end laptop with amd athlon silver and 4gb of ram and 1tb of hdd with windows 10 home edition, when i first buy it for coding purpose it never had any problem than a little bit of lag when i open something that too heavy for my slow laptop.
Problem occur when im no longer do coding in this laptop, instead im using it for internet browsing mainly youtube and a little bit of gaming, when i play game for a couple hours yes it gets a little warm yet it never freeze completely, but sometime when im watching youtube it will randomly freezing to the point i cant do anything about it that make me do force shutdown with pressing the power button for 5 sec.

What should i do to fix it?
upgrade my ram? or should i change to ssd and move my windows to ssd?
i already search how to fix it on google and doing everything but it seems the freezing keep happening again and again.

Comment: Are you using Chrome? turn off the 'Use hardware acceleration when available' in settings -> advanced settings and test again.
Which is part of youtube performance, Youtube use CPU/GPU to decode videos, keep this off on old and low end laptops.

Comment: yes im using chrome or moreover chromebase browser like opera and edge, ill get back if its work. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Investing in memory and SSD (much needed here) on a low end machine is often a waste of money.

Get memtest86.exe, the hard drive manufacturer's test app, and if possible the general motherboard test app from the computer manufacturer.

Test all the hardware you can to see if there is a hardware fault. This seems somewhat probable here.

If you or a friend can open the laptop, carefully clean out accumulated dust especially from the fan. Use care here.

If you can do all the above and if all seems normal, then you can consider investing in upgraded hardware (memory and SSD).  An SSD is like day and night compared to a slow HDD.

Good luck with this.

Comment: i already check everything, and it was fine.
i guess i just try to buy a small ssd

Comment: That is probably the thing to do and if you can, also added memory.